# Custom Dialog is being dismissed when I click outside of it

Tags: android, dialog

I have a custom dialog that dismisses when you click outside of the dialog, which is what I do not want.  Having `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` does not fix the problem.  What am I doing wrong?

```
dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.twitter_dialog);
// set up edit text and other widgets
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(450, 280);
dialog.show();
```

EDIT:  I am calling this dialog from another dialog that has setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true).  Before this dialog is called, the previous dialog is dismissed.

Comment: remove this line and tell us what happens: `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(450, 280);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using AlertDialog

Comment: For me, the AlertDialog can also be dismissed if you touch it outside its area.

Answer (score 14):

you can use getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Answer (score 8):

This work for me:

```
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the sample code

```
EditDialog newDialog = new EditDialog();
newDialog .setCancelable(false);   ///This will prevent closing the dialog on back button press/ touch outside
newDialog .show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog");
```